# Estimate gas price with ethers.js

Tags: gas, gas-estimate, ethers.js

I'm looking to estimate transaction fees in an application. In order to do so I need to estimate the current gas price before I execute the transaction.

I see web3.js has a `getGasPrice` method:
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth.html#getgasprice

Is there a similar method in ethers.js? Or what is the recommended approach here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found it!
https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider-getGasPrice

Hint: the search functionality on docs.ethers.io isn't great - this method didn't show up by searching for "gasprice":
https://docs.ethers.io/v5/search/?search=gasprice

Answer (score 21):

There is a method called [estimateGas](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#contract-estimateGas) in the `Contract` class. Example for how to use it:

```js
const erc20Abi = [ /* ... */ ];
const address = "TOKEN_ADDRESS_HERE";
const provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider();
const erc20 = new ethers.Contract(address, abi, provider);

const recipient = "SOME_ADDRESS_HERE";
const estimation = await erc20.estimateGas.transfer(recipient, 100);
```

Caveats:

1. You have to be connected to a provider, but luckily this is easy to do with the `getDefaultProvider` function.
2. Don't expect the gas estimation to be super precise, especially when your contract call is making additional calls to other contracts.

Comment: Thanks Paul! I did see the `estimateGas` method but that returns the "units of gas that would be required". In order to arrive at the transaction fee, don't I need both units of gas AND the gas price? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/how-to-calculate-transaction-fee

Comment: Whoops, I misunderstood your question. Sorry. Check out my [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6792/how-to-get-the-actual-gas-price/78126#78126) in the [How to get the actual gas price](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/6792/24693) thread.

Comment: Got it, thanks! So no ability to query this within ethers.js directly?

Comment: It looks like you found the answer - the `getGasPrice` function.

Comment: are you sure this works? who is the from address in this case? it will fail with `ERC20: transfer from the zero address`. When you create the erc20 variable you will need a signer, also the signer must have at least the amount you want to send as balance. If you want to use the default provider, you have to override the `from` attribute.

Answer (score 13):

As of 2022 you should use [getFeeData() since getGasPrice() has been deprecated](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/discussions/2439#discussioncomment-1857403). This accounts for network fee changes introduced in EIP-1559. The creator of Ethers.js talks about this in the above link and also provided an example of how to use it.

`getFeeData()` documentation: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider-getFeeData

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'd like to say that [the third top answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/127320) and [second top answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/100215) are correct but vague. [The top answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/100210) also implicitly relies on the use of a `Contract` and a `DefaultProvider` which is not ideal because a custom provider is much more practical, and you don't always have a `Contract` to rely on for estimating gas. I had some difficulty with the migration so I am going to share a working example here for everyone.

If you're using TypeScript, the import should look like this:

```typescript
import { ethers } from "ethers";
```

To create a `provider`, you can use the following line:

```typescript
const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("some_provider_url");
```

As the other answers suggested, you can use `provider#getFeeData()`:

```typescript
const feeData = await provider.getFeeData();
```

I also had issues processing the output, but instead of using `ethers.utils.formatUnits`, we now use `ethers.formatUnits`:

```typescript
// These are not in a very useful format
let gasPrice = feeData.gasPrice;
let maxFeePerGas = feeData.maxFeePerGas;
let maxPriorityFeePerGas = feeData.maxPriorityFeePerGas;

// Convert the gas price from Wei to Gwei or Ether for better readability
const gasPriceInEth = ethers.formatUnits(gasPrice, 'ether');
const gasPriceInGwei = ethers.formatUnits(gasPrice, 'gwei');
const gasPriceInWei = ethers.formatUnits(gasPrice, 'wei');
```

Should be more than enough to help anyone else with migration issues as well.