# how to calculate the gas fee of my nft mint transaction

Tags: gas, gas-price, gas-estimate

I have the following function to mint a nft on my smart contract (I am using the open zeppelin ERC721 contract) but I would like to stimate the gas feet from my web3 dapp. I know the formula is `transaction cost * current gas price` and I know I can find the current gas price using something like etherscan api or the ethgasstation.info api, and I know the minimum transaction cost is 21000 but I don't know how much is the `cost`of my mint function in other to calculate a realistic gas fee for the minting, any help to calculate or to find my transaction cost?

here is my mint function:

```
function mint(uint256[] memory tokens) public payable {
        require(saleIsActive, "Sale is not active");
        if (
            tokens.length == 0 || tokens > maxPurchase
        ) {
            revert("number of tokens incorrect");
        }
        if (price * tokens.length >= msg.value) {
            revert("Ether value is not correct");
        }
        if (_totalTokens.current() + tokens.length > MAX_TOKENS) {
            revert("Purchase would exceed max supply");
        }

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            _safeMint(msg.sender, gradisTokens[i]);
            _totalTokens.increment();
        }
    }
```

Comment: first, get rid please of those ifs, you can change them all to require(condition, revetString).
What you can do is run the function on ganache or test net and see how much gas your mint function consumes for that specific input. There is a method to estimate gas price but no idea if it works correctly https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth-contract.html?highlight=estimate#methods-mymethod-estimategas

Comment: and check this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/100209/estimate-gas-price-with-ethers-js

Comment: @MajdTL thanks for your help. If I change the "ifs" for a require I always get the error even though the condition is the same and I don't know why

Comment: you do need to invert the conditions, don’t you? Like require(tokens.length != 0 && tokens < maxPurchase, „revert message“) :/ for the first If